# Why static variable change?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, static-variables

I'm having some problems using static variables in python. I'm trying to have a counter of the number of processes(the class called *Node*). In the initialization everything is fine, but after the static variable *num_node* start to have 2 different value. In the main have the right value, the number of Nodes created, but if I print it on an instance of Node it is reset to 0

(English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part)

### This is my class Node:

```
class Node(Process):
    num_node = 0

    @classmethod
    def increase(cls):
        Node.num_node += 1

    @classmethod
    def get_num_node(cls):
        return Node.num_node

    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Process, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        Node.increase()
        print("Number of node in the INIT of NODE: {}".format(Node.get_num_node()))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.queue.get()
            print("Number of node inside the NODE: {}".format(Node.get_num_node()))
```

### This is the main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nodes = []
    # CREATE 3 NODE
    for i in range(2):
        p = Node(Queue())
        p.start()
        nodes.append(p)
        print("Number of node inside the MAIN: ", Node.get_num_node())

    msg = input("\nInsert message> ")
    for n in nodes:
        n.queue.put((msg, 0))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Number of node inside the MAIN: ", Node.get_num_node())
```

And when I run it the output is:

```
Number of node in the INIT of NODE: 1
Number of node inside the MAIN:  1
Number of node in the INIT of NODE: 2
Number of node inside the MAIN:  2

Insert message> 0
Number of node inside the NODE: 0
Number of node inside the NODE: 0
Number of node inside the MAIN:  2
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: unrelated:  `range(2)`  ==> `[0,1]` - only 2 nodes

Comment: I am not very fluent with Python processes, but I could imagine that the change of this class member is not propagate among the other processes. For inter process communication, you need special structures (e. g. the Queue you already use). See https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html.

Comment: I cannot exactly reproduce (last three prints, I get 1 2 2 instead of your 0 0 2) but indeed the classes are in different process (=> different instances) so do not share num_node.

Comment: Processes run in separate memory-spaces, so there's an independent `Node` _class_ in each one, and each of them has its own class attribute (what you are calling a "static" variable) which is independent of the values in any of the others.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that variables do not transfer between processes. Instead, when you spawn a new process, it inherits whatever variables there are at the time of process creation but updates to these do not propagate to another processes already running.

After updating the range clause in comments to create three processes, this is what happens:

```
Number of node in the INIT of NODE: 1
Number of node inside the MAIN:  1
Number of node in the INIT of NODE: 2
Number of node inside the MAIN:  2
Number of node in the INIT of NODE: 3
Number of node inside the MAIN:  3

Insert message> 0
Number of node inside the NODE: 1
Number of node inside the NODE: 2
Number of node inside the NODE: 3
Number of node inside the MAIN:  3
```

Your first child process started with num_node of 0 and then incremented it by one. Now the class has num_node of 1. When you created your second child, it started with num_node of 1 and incremented it by one. Which means now your first process has num_node of 1 and the second process 2. And so on.

You can fix this by replacing your num_node with a Manager. They are helpers that carry variables between processes.

This should now do the trick:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Manager
import time


class Node(Process):
    num_node = Manager().Value("h",0)

    @classmethod
    def increase(cls):
        Node.num_node.value += 1

    @classmethod
    def get_num_node(cls):
        return Node.num_node.value

    ...



if __name__ == '__main__':
    nodes = []
    # CREATE 3 NODE
    for i in range(3):
        ...
```

The output looks now like this:

```
Number of node in the INIT of NODE: 1
Number of node inside the MAIN:  1
Number of node in the INIT of NODE: 2
Number of node inside the MAIN:  2
Number of node in the INIT of NODE: 3
Number of node inside the MAIN:  3

Insert message> 0
Number of node inside the NODE: 3
Number of node inside the NODE: 3
Number of node inside the NODE: 3
Number of node inside the MAIN:  3
```

Comment: I get a RuntimeError if I run this:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

Comment: Odd. It works fine on my computer (python 3.5 used to test)

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: No I am not. Does the OPs code run on yours? I just copypasted it and changed one variable to a Manager, I did not tinker with the process creation part.

Comment: OPs code is running. I think the problem is that I am using windows. Good answer nevertheless.

Comment: I get a RuntimeError too. Using windows on python 3.7

Comment: Bugger.  I do not have a windows to test it.    Did you originally have just one single file or did you have your main in one file and the class in another? If yes, can you try with the same file structure as you had before?

Comment: Apparently there is an issue with Windows but the `if __name__` ... statement should protect against it.  Sorry I can't help with a Windows problem but your issue in diverging variables would be solved by using a `Manager()`